# Perforce: client root of client in different directory

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have two directories say X and Y.
I am in directory X and want to know the "client root" of the client which is specified by .p4config file in one of the parent directories of directory Y.
I don't know the name of the client also.

How do I know the client root? I tried with **p4 -d Y info** but no luck.

Comment: Never mind. I have a p4 alias to "p4 -d /bin/pwd". That's why it was not working. Unaliasing p4 followed by "p4 -d Y info" works fine.